# Firebase Web - Signout - Cannot delete property '0' of [object Array]

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error every time I try to signout from firebase (web)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property '0' of [object Array]
```

Here is a screenshot of the error in the browser

[image]

This is how I use auth

```
 onLogout = () => {
   auth.signOut().then(() => {
     alert("Success");
   });
 };

...

<div onClick={this.onLogout}>
    <i className="ni ni-user-run" />
    <span>Logout</span>
</div>
```

and how I register

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/storage";

const config = {
  apiKey: "##",
  authDomain: "##",
  databaseURL: "##",
  projectId: "##",
  storageBucket: "##",
  messagingSenderId: "##",
  appId: "##",
  measurementId: "##",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

Comment: Can you please share your complete code?  I don't see any arrays in the code that you have shared. Also a screenshot of the error in the browser console would be helpful.

Comment: I've added more code and a screenshot of the error in the browser

Comment: Can you wrap the code in a try catch please ? ```onLogout = () => {
   auth.signOut().then(() => {
     try {
       alert("Success");
    } catch(e) { console.log(e) }
   });
 };```

Comment: tried it! nothing happens. The error seems to be on the firebase auth side. Also, if I catch the promise exception I get the same response. So something brokes inside `signOut`

Comment: Tbh that's working fine on my side. Can you please try importing the FirebaseSDK and initializing it in the file where you are calling the function directly? I have seen people facing issues when they import it from other files.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!

The error happened because I stored the entire `user` response from firebase in redux.

```
if (doc.exists) {
    const auth = { ...user, ...doc.data() };
    dispatch(fetchRestaurantAsync(auth.restaurantUid));
    dispatch(setAuthData(auth));
}
```

where user is

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.props.fetchPartnerAsync(user);
});
```

The solution was to store only what I wanted from that object!